# Change fan speed with Python + OpenHardwareMonitor

Tags: python, openhardwaremonitor

I'm making a little custom application with Python and TKinter to change settings for gaming and such, I already have it setup to change my power plan. Now I'm trying to change the speed of my fans, I can already do this separately in OpenHardwareMonitor(for the case fans) and Radeon Software(for the GPU fans). Is there anyway I can do both of these through code?

Comment: Could you post what you have done or tried to do so we can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a great guide to asking good questions.

Comment: I really haven't tried anything, I found a post on here that mentioned checking OHM's .dll file but I have no idea how to make use of what I find in there.